# OpenGL 4.4 rendering just white screen

Tags: c++, opengl

I am trying to build an **OpenGL 4.4** Windows application.

For that I am manually getting pointers to function using **wglGetProcAddress**; i.e. **not using GLEW, GLEE or FreeGLUT**.

Code builds correctly, but I get white screen and nothing else, i.e. triangle is not drawn on the screen.

System configuration

- OS : Windows 7 SP1 64 bit
- GPU : NVIDIA GTX 750 Ti
- DRIVER : NVIDIA 337.88 (latest)

Here's Visual Studio project files :[VS 2010 Project](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B7Fzj3VZLTWWdnAyQkl6Y2I5Yk0/edit?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are never calling **SetData()** function in your program.
So how can you expect to get any result on the screen.

In your **Win32_Window.cpp** :

```
...
ShowWindow(hWnd, nCmdShow);
UpdateWindow(hWnd);

SetupPixelFormat();
InitGL();
SetData();           // Add this line to set data for VAO and VBO
```